# How to get teamviwer voip work

Tags: teamviewer

I'm using Ubuntu 13. 10 and teamviewer8, it's work perfect with remote controlling stuff, but when I want to use its Voip with meeting it said to me: `please connect a microphone` and `please connect speakers`

[image: skype voip section]

I tried to setup voice from wine config but it seems to work fine and my mic is working great with `skype`

Comment: Is the problem reproducible?

Comment: I have the same probelm